# Creating virtual directories within another virtual directory using C#

Tags: c#, iis-7, virtual-directory

I created a windows Service app which knows how to create virtual directories in the root folder of the IIS (7.5).

And this is the code:

`System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.IISVirtualRoot vr =
                        new System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.IISVirtualRoot();`

`string sError = "";`

`vr.Create("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root", physicalPath, virtualDirectoryName, out sError);`

This works perfecly.

Now, lets say I created a virtual dir named `MyVDir` within the ROOT folder, and then I want to create another virtual dir, with the same c# function as above - within the `MyVDir` virtual directory (create nested virtual directory). What should I do?

Something like `vr.Create("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root/MyVDir", physicalPath, virtualDirectoryName, out sError);` doesn't work for me, and throws an `'Cannot find path'` exception.

Thanks all!

Comment: Don't flag a question for mods because you need an answer.